# Can sqlalchemy update where statements use LIKE?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to find records where I have a partial name of one of the column values. In mysql you're able to say

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] LIKE '%blah%';
```

Can you do the same with sqlalchemy?
ex.

```
u = sqlalchemy.update([table]).where([table].c.[column] LIKE '%blah%')
```

Comment: Yes. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#inserts-updates-and-deletes. There's an example using LIKE (through `startswith()`) in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#multiple-table-updates.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed.